# Can't preselect time zone in hook_form_alter

Tags: forms, 9, installation-profiles

I'm writing a custom installation profile/distribution and I want to pre-populate some fields in the 'Configure Site' form (`/core/install.php`).
I have managed to prefill/preselect other fields like (`Site name`, `Site email address` and `Default country`) but cannot preselect the `Default time zone` field. This is the code I am using:

```
function mydistribution_form_install_configure_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['site_information']['site_name']['#default_value'] = 'Dummy Site Name';
  $form['site_information']['site_mail']['#default_value'] = 'example@example.com';
  
  $form['regional_settings']['site_default_country']['#default_value'] = 'DE';
  $form['regional_settings']['date_default_timezone']['#default_value'] = 'Europe/Berlin';
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot, I manage to change the `Default country` successfully, but not the `Default time zone`.

The "strange" thing though is that when I inspect the code, I can see that the correct timezone has been `selected` but the form displays `London`.

[image]

I'm based in the UK so I guess this is how London gets selected.

Does anyone know how to get this fixed? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal adds some JS to detect the timezone (through core/misc/timezone.js). This is interfering with your code, but can be removed easily:

```
unset($form['regional_settings']['date_default_timezone']['#attributes']);
```

This removes the `timezone-detect` class from the `<select>`, stopping it from being processed by the JS.

Comment: Thank you so much Clive! That resolved my issue.